# Size of Integer in Mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I couldn`t find the number on limit for the Integer in Mongomapper.
May it convert a 'big integer' to LongInt in MongoDB automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bson library handles this for you / mongomapper. If the thing you are trying to serialise is a bignum/fixnum it checks whether it will fit into a 4 byte or 8 byte integer and encodes it correspondingly. It actually checks the value, since a Fixnum limits don't match the 4 byte /byte boundaries that mongo has.

The corresponding bit of the driver is [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/ext/cbson/cbson.c#L243)

Comment: Isn't that bit of code rejecting integers that do not fit in the signed 64 bit integer range? I don't see any automatic conversion code.

Comment: Correct - bson can't represent such integers. What that code does do is ensure that things that fit in 32 bit integers are stored using bson's 4 byte type and that those that fit in 8 bytes are stored in bson's 8 byte type. If you're out of that range you're out of luck.

Comment: Ah okay, misinterpretation of your owner on my part ;)

Answer (score 0):

The integer data type depends on the what Mongo installation you chose. If you chose 32 bit, the integer goes up to 32 bits, so about 2 billion. Choosing the 64 bit install is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores its data in the BSON format (*that's binary JSON*). [The specification for BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) supports both 32-bit and 64-bit integers.

The key here is going to be your Ruby driver and configuration.